# First overall draft picks getting traded for one another

Tags: nfl, mlb, nba, nhl, trade

The Detroit Lions traded away their quarterback Mathew Stafford, in exchange for LA Ram's quarterback Jared Goff, 2 first round picks and a third round pick on January 30th 2021. The most interesting part about this trade (at least to me) is that both of these players were first overall draft picks. Stafford was the first overall pick of the [2009 draft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_NFL_Draft#Player_selections), and Goff was the first overall pick of the [2016 draft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_NFL_Draft#Player_selections).

Have 2 (or more) first overall draft picks (first pick of the first round of a draft) ever been been involved in the a trade in any of the  North American big 4 leagues (NFL, MLB, NBA, NHL)?

Comment: Yes I mean specifically the overall first round pick, ie first pick of the first round. Will make this more clear in the question.

Comment: FWIW, I looked through the past top draft picks for the leagues other than the NBA, and I don't see any, unless there's an MLB trade of top picks at some point where one of them was a total bust and just a throw-in (very possible, MLB top picks fail a lot).  But I didn't go back to, like, the 1900s or anything like that, would need a data driven process to give an answer. The OJ Simpson trade might be the closest (ended up being for a top pick, but the pick wasn't made yet or even known to be #1), if you count that.

Answer (score 3):

In 2012, Andrew Bogut (1st overall in 2005) was traded to Golden State in exchange for a package including Kwame Brown (1st overall in 2001).

Comment: Nice find - although well into the "meh" portion of both players' careers (Bogut was still starting caliber, but only for his defense really, he neither scored nor rebounded much, and Kwame played very little in 2012-13 and then retired), it certainly meets the criteria!

Comment: Thank you. Not the most exciting trade ever but Bogut was a key contributor on that 2015 championship team as well as on the 73 win team. Just one of the many solid moves by the Warriors in gearing up for their dynasty. I actually found this by looking at Kwame’s career, I knew he had been traded a few times and figured that one of his trades could meet the criteria.